# Django - Update each field in the database that have this value

Tags: python, django, database, django-models, updates

Let's say I have two tables:

**table#1: Space**

[image]

**table#2: Students**

[image]

If I want to change the prom_name form table#1, I'd like to automatically update the prom_name in my table#2 as well

My model Students is a Form where students insert their name and the prom_code(given), if the prom_code does not exist then it Deny the registration

```
class Space(model.Models):
    prom_name = models.CharField(max_length = 20)
    prom_code = models.CharField(max_length = 20, Default=RANDOM, editable=FALSE)

    def save(self):
        try:
            From my_other_app.models import Students
            myobj = Students.object.get(prom_code = self.prom_code)
            myobj.prom_name = self.prom_name
            myobj.save()
        except Students.DoesNotExist:
        super(Space, self).save()
```

This is Just a simple example of what I'm trying to do, the original one its already validate if the register is new and so

I Just can't get how to change all my prom_names from every prom_code = self.prom_code (The one I'm changing) in my table Students

Do I need to use a for cycle?

Regards,

Comment: You have `Prom_code` and `Prom_name` in both tables. It looks like your database / models are not Normalized. If you normalize your database, you don't need to update `Prom_name` in each table if it is changed in one table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your design is not in compliance with [2nd normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_normal_form). The `Prom_name` should only exists in table `Space` but not in `Students`, because storing redundant field would only add additional disk space and increase maintenance work like the one you just described.

You should delete `Prom_name` column from `Students` table and do a join when you need to get the name with `Space` table.

Comment: You are right, since my prom_code is unique,  I could just call my prom_name with the value I've or not change, Thanks alot, my mistake

Answer (score 1):

You could normalize your database (by changing the models) in such a way:

**table#1: Space**

```
Prom_code  |   Prom_name
789             Prom1
800             Prom5
471             Prom3
```

**table#2: Students**

```
Name    |   ID    |    Prom_code
John         1           789
Martha       2           789   
Ramsy        3           800
Bob          4           471
Debbys       5           789
```

The **Prom_code** in **Students** table is a **foreign key** referring to **Prom_code** in **Space** table.

Comment: Thanks Alot my friend, I just realize my mistake in database design